# How can a runnable jar load external xml file at runtime?

Tags: java, xml, maven, jar

(This seems like a trivial enough problem, but stuck for 2 days :( )

I have a runnable jar (created with `maven assembly plugin`). A class inside the jar looks for an xml file on classpath. However, we do not want to bundle the xml file in the jar and want it to be externalized.

Tried till now:

1. Set the classpath at runtime:

   ```
   java -classpath ./conf -jar my-jar-with-dependencies.jar
   ```

==> doesn't load (conf folder contains the xml)

2. Set classpath in assembler plugin

   ```
           <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>make-assembly</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>single</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
               <archive>
                   <manifest>
                       <mainClass>com.xxx.Test</mainClass>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       <classpathPrefix>./conf/</classpathPrefix>
                   </manifest>
               </archive>
               <descriptorRefs>
                   <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
               </descriptorRefs>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```

==> does not add ClassPath to MANIFEST.MF in the runnable jar

**Edit:**

Generated `MAINFEST.MF` in the jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: xxx
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_21
Main-Class: com.xxx.Test
```

**Edit 2**:

So I edited the generated `MANIFEST` in the jar and recreated jar. Still doesn't find the xml!

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: xxx
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_21
Main-Class: com.xxx.Test
Class-Path: . /* Tried with both . and ./conf */
```

Comment: You can use this:     InputStream stream1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/resource.xml"); 
    or 
    InputStream stream2 = getClass().getResourceAsStream("path/resource.xml"); to load external resource

Comment: The code that loads the xml is in an external library (which also gets bundled with the assembled jar). I do not have access to that code. It just looks for the xml on classpath at runtime. All I want to do is make sure that library finds the xml - though from an external folder and not bundled inside the jar. It should not matter to that library where the xml is physically located.

Comment: The location where your jar is present must be on classpath. Can you not just put it at the same location (as your jar file)?

Comment: I tried that - put the xml in the same folder as jar and ran `java -jar` from that folder. Still doesnt find...

Comment: Is main class appear in manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a good answer to this. In summary:

- `java -jar` ignores `-cp` option
- Adding `ClassPath` to `manifset` has no effect either (not sure if it is due to any particular way of how the library loads the xml)

So, the only remaining option that works is to invoke the class file manually:

```
$ java -cp <...> MyPackage.MyClass
```

where, cp contains the jar file and conf folder path.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `-jar` argument classpath you specify is ignored. It is specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

JVM use classpath specified in manifest. Make sure that manifest contains classpath definition.

Comment: Any reference that `-jar` option ignores `-classpath`? I tried adding the `classpath` with the second option in my question. Looks like I might have missed something with the assembler plugin configuration.

Comment: Added proof for first part of answer.